# Infinite simple p-groups with only trivial irreps in characteristic p

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Is there a prime $p$ and an infinite simple $p$-group $G$ such that for any field $K$ of characteristic $p$ the only irreducible $KG$-module, whether finite or infinite dimensional, is trivial (that is, the augmentation ideal and Jacobson radical of $KG$ coincide)?

If this has appeared in print, a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: According to http://www.math.wisc.edu/~passman/trento.pdf such a group cannot be finitely generated.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think the same ideas show that for such a group the Jacobson radical (a.k.a. augmentation ideal) must be an idempotent ideal of $KG$.